# Why are my images being loaded as the Admin Login page?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cms, static-block, admin-login, media-images

I'm trying to fix an issue where a user is unable to save changes in the backend as they are being kicked back to the admin login page even though they hasn't been logged in long enough for the session to have expired.

As they were trying to update a static block with an image via the WYSIWYG i looked there and was able to replicate the problem and found that a number of images aren't loading. looking in the Developer Tools for Chrome i see this

[image]

in the image above all those are meant to be images yet some have the type detected as text/html, the one i am hovering over clearly shows it's being loaded from the images directory and i can confirm it's a legit image (by locating the url in the DOM and getting the actual file that was supposed to load via the `<img>`'s alt attribute).

[image]

this image was taken from Microsoft Edge's Developer Tools where i have a body tab when looking at a file in the network section, you can see a small bit of HTML which explains why the image is being detected as text/html, the HTML being what's generated when you're presented with the login page.

I believe the user being kicked back to the login page is related to these images not being loaded as images but as the admin login page as if i leave the page to another page (like manage customers) before the images start doing this i am not kicked back to the login page while if i wait i am.

My question is why are these images being loaded as the Admin Login page? and how can i fix this?

EDIT: we have a Dev Enviroment which uses the exact same code though database content is different as it has test data. there is a different with the Media Gallery but only by 8 images which combines is only ~0.4mb. the only difference between this dev and live enviroment is that Dev doesn't use membase and this Redis thing that's set up in the local.xml file in app/etc

Comment: Is this only a problem in Internet Explorer or also in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl as you can see in the question this happens in Chrome and Edge. i have't tested firefox but i very much doubt it'll work in Firefox and i have IE11 uninstalled because my PC resets the default web browser back to IE11 when i shut down and having it uninstalled means that anything that would require IE11 to use will prompt for a new program and i can set Chrome

Comment: Oh sorry, overlooked this.

Comment: Are you using any admin specific extensions / extensions that have impact on the admin? They might instantiate a session to early or in a wrong way. If you can reproduce this on a local dev environment it might be wise to disable all custom extensions and see if you can reproduce.

Comment: @ToonVanDooren to my understanding no however there are a few extensions. this site was brought as it is and no new extensions have been added and this problem has only started occurring recently

Comment: Ok, what are you using for session handling? Files? Redis? Memcached?

Comment: @ToonVanDooren it's almost like you read my mind. in the local.xml where in a vanilla build it would say `files` for an xml node called session it now says `memcache`. there is also xml bellow it for a cache saying something about Redis

Comment: Could you change it to files to see if the problem persists? I am not experienced with Memcached sessions as I prefer Redis session since we can be more certain of the stability there.

Comment: @ToonVanDooren sorry for the late response as i was at home and not at work. because it's a live site i'm hesitant to do that however the dev site, where this wasn't happening, i changed `session_save` where it said `files` to `memcache` and low and behold Dev is now doing the same as Live. reverting it back fixes the problem. while it seems setting `session_save` to `files` fixes it i would still like to know why this is happening and if it's something that can be fixed so that we can keep the `memcache` setting

Comment: @ToonVanDooren actually now it's happening again. set as `files` the problem does it less often and this is on the live site

Comment: @Memor-X I can advise to migrate you sessions on live to Redis for starters. I would also take a look at your session lifetime to see if it is long enough.